# Postmaster plugin: user activation link

Tags: emails, registration, activation

Trying to get the [Postmaster plugin](https://github.com/objectivehtml/Postmaster-for-Craft-CMS) working for user activation emails, instead of the default Craft setup (had issue with Mandrill setup, Use SMTP authentication throws an error).

1. It doesn't seem that Postmaster disables the default Craft email setup, is there a way to do this within Craft?
2. Assuming (1), what is the correct `{{ link }}` variable as currently I'm seeing:

   Template Error

   Variable "link" does not exist

   /Users/.../site/craft/templates/postmaster/user/activation.txt(5)

   Hey {{user.friendlyName}},

   Thanks for creating an account with the Postmaster {{siteName}}! To  activate your account, click the following link:

   {{link}}

   If you weren't expecting this email, just ignore it.

It doesn't seem there is currently a way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Craft 2.x, it isn't possible for plugins to provide their own email providers that the entire Craft installation can use.  They can provide their own that they can use for themselves, but it won't affect things like when Craft sends an activation email.

That's changed in the upcoming [Craft 3](http://buildwithcraft.com/3), though.  There is an example Mandrill plugin [here](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/Mandrill) on how to pull that off.

Comment: Good to know, and great to know it's set for Craft 3. Exciting to see what's coming up, hopefully not too far into the future!

Comment: FYI: Mandrill SMTP was a local install issue, works fine on live server. No idea why, as I'm pretty sure all the PHP extensions are there on AMPPS (Mac) — throws an ssl error. There's a similar issue somewhere on here, but can't track it down now.